# Key and Multi-line python value

Tags: python, string

I am trying to read a text file or use the `ConfigParser` on a file with the following structure

```
        Index1 = '''You have been redirected to this page for one of the following 

        reasons:

        Either cookies are not enabled on your browser
        or
        Your network configuration is causing cookies to be lost or not function properly.
        IEEE Xplore requires cookies to maintain sessions and to access licensed content. Cookies are used temporarily to maintain sessions in 
        IEEE Xplore and for no other purpose.'''

        Index2 = '''Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8
        Click Tools menu.
        Select Internet Options.
        Select Privacy tab. 
        Click the Default button or slide the bar down to 'Medium'.
        Click Ok. '''
```

I would like to be able to give it the key value `Index1` and get the string block after it or iterate through all the Index values and get the blocks after them. I can't seem to read more than one line from the string

So far I tried

```
for line in fileinput.input('config.conf'):
    part = line.partition("'''")
    ts = part[0]
    st = part[1]
```

Comment: please show the code that you currently have on how you are reading the file. if you are iterating through like `for line in file` then reminder that this iterates through each line with `\n` as a delimiter

Answer (score 1):

One approach to solve the problem is to have a config.ini file like

```
[Multiline Values]
Index1 : You have been redirected to this page for one of the following
    reasons:
    Either cookies are not enabled on your browser
    or
    Your network configuration is causing cookies to be lost or not function properly.
    IEEE Xplore requires cookies to maintain sessions and to access licensed content. Cookies are used temporarily to maintain sessions in
    IEEE Xplore and for no other purpose.
```

and read it like:

```
import ConfigParser
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read('config.ini')
val = Config.get('Multiline Values', 'Index1')
print val
```

output:

```
You have been redirected to this page for one of the following
reasons:
Either cookies are not enabled on your browser
or
Your network configuration is causing cookies to be lost or not function properly.
IEEE Xplore requires cookies to maintain sessions and to access licensed content. Cookies are used temporarily to maintain sessions in
IEEE Xplore and for no other purpose.
```

The header name 'Multiline Values' and key name 'Index1' could be anything.

Comment: I tried this approach but I get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  `code File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    Config.read('hashdoop.ini')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 546, in _read
    raise e
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: config.ini
 [line  4]: 'Avangar Technologies announces the beginning of a new unprecendented global employment campaign. \n'`

Comment: can you please upload your config file line 0 to line 5-6 on some anonymous text sharing website? like https://gist.github.com/